# How do I program BTC Relay into my dapp?

Tags: btcrelay

The [description of BTC Relay](http://btcrelay.org/) seems pretty cool.  So how do I use it practically?

Dumb question - I'm a non technical person.  Let's say I was building an estore which runs off of contracts.  How would I code in HTML or Java BTC Relay.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in the subject.